# How can I solve systems of equations of the following form?

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equations that I would like to solve / find solutions for certain variables:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&&&&\newline
-1&1&x_{1}&x_{2}&&&\newline
&x_{3}&1&x_{4}&&&\newline
&x_{5}&x_{6}&1&&&\newline
&x_{7}&x_{8}&x_{9}&1&&\newline
&x_{10}&x_{11}&x_{12}&&1&\newline
&x_{13}&x_{14}&x_{15}&&&1\newline
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
a\newline
y_{1}\newline
y_{2}\newline
y_{3}\newline
\frac{a}{3}\newline
\frac{a}{3}\newline
\frac{a}{3}\newline
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a\newline
0\newline
0\newline
0\newline
0\newline
0\newline
0\newline
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Specifically, I want to find solutions for {$x_{1},...,x_{15}$}, where $x_{i}∈ ${$-\frac{1}{2},0$}, $y_{i}>0$, and $a$ is some unknown constant. I'm not sure if this is possible to solve faster than brute force checking. Additionally, this should be generalizable to matrices where the number of $x$s per row and size of the matrix can be different. If this seems like an "ask to solve x, actually needs to solve y" problem, please let me know I will provide more details.